# Login failed for existing user while adding database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I've created a new MVC project and am creating a new database by following [this](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part2.htm) tutorial. But on adding an SQL Server Database, it gives the following error.

"Login failed for user 'JM-VCACMASTER03\admin"

I tried adding an existing database as given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/496447/Linking-to-an-Existing-SQLDB-in-ASP-MVC-and-EF) and it adds it successfully. Whats going wrong with the first approach?

Comment: which method you follow ? windows authentication or sql server authentication?

Comment: Windows authentication in SQL Server and I've enabled Windows Authentication in the Project properties.

Answer (score 0):

try this method 
Open `SQL Management Studio` 
Open `Object Explorer`
Then right click `Database`
then Select `New DataBase`
And Create `Tables` what u actually want

then connect New `Database` from your `VisualStudio` and Then Open `tools`  then `connect to database`
 and connect using windows authentication . You need to give your server name there 
If it added as sucessfully then take `ConnectionString` and then use it in your program for connection

Comment: then what is your problem ? i think your problem is create a new database and then connect to that database from your code . am i right ?

Comment: If u have still the error then Go to SQL Management Studio then Create a new login  by right clicking the security section in object explorer and select new- then login and define username and password their and then use that username and password when u connect(User sql authentication insted of windows when u connecting )

Comment: How do I enable SQL Server authentication while connecting to the DB from Visual Studio?

Comment: the same procedure u can follow  tools->connect to database->enter your server name , then enable "use sql server authentication " rather than "use windows authentication " then Enter your Sql Login username and password"